# How to provide a background color for an entire row in ag grid based on a certain value in a column?

Tags: ag-grid

I need to provide  a background color for an entire row in ag grid based on a condition in a column. I found no such examples where entire row is colored based on a certain value in a column..

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The previous answer is somewhat outdated (although still correct and working) and now we have some more control over the styling of the grid. You could use `getRowStyle(params)` for this job, just like this:

```
gridOptions.getRowStyle(params) {
    if (params.data.myColumnToCheck === myValueToCheck) {
        return {'background-color': 'yellow'}
    }
    return null;
}
```

Obviously, `myColumnToCheck` would be the column you're checking your value against (the same name you input in the id/field property of the colDef object), and `myValueToCheck` would be the value you want said column to have to make the row all yellow.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be documented on the ag-grid site (http://angulargrid.com) but it works :) Much better than having to style every cell individually!

Comment: Do you know how you'd keep the selected row color working when this function is active?  I've noticed selected rows no longer change their background color when a custom getRowStyle is enabled.

Comment: Can't seem to get getRowClass on gridOptions  to work. Prefer to use css class for the style.

Comment: If the style doesn't depend on the cell values, or if the cell values are within a well-known set (like monday, tuesday, etc) then yes, adding a class and using css on it is the way to go. It's how I usually do what I need.

Comment: Thanks rowClassRules was not working for me this worked.

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/row-styles/

Comment: In 2023  (`ag-grid-react 28.2`) this is still almost entirely correct. I only had to return `{}` instead of `null` to silence the TypeScript compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Answer 2 is correct, but the syntax used is wrong, and caused me several problems trying to sort it out. Trying to minify the answer 2 code barfed, for example. It did work, but it's not proper syntax as far as I can see.

Note, this can be done inline, or with an external
function. For example an external function.

```
vm.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    getRowStyle: getRowStyleScheduled
}

function getRowStyleScheduled(params) {
    if (params.selected && params.data.status === 'SCHEDULED') {
        return {
            'background-color': '#455A64',
            'color': '#9AA3A8'
    }
    } else if (params.data.status === 'SCHEDULED') {
        return {
            'background-color': '#4CAF50',
            'color': '#F4F8F5'
        };
    }
    return null;
};
```

Comment: I think answer 2 would work for a grid already instantiated. I believe it would have to be followed by a grid refresh. My answer is oriented to grid configuration before instantiation.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps others. A very common use case in any table or grid including AG Grid is going to be to set the even/odd background color of the whole row of the entire table in a performant way. ALSO, this needs to still work when SORTING.

ALL OF THESE WAYS OF DOING THIS IN AG-GRID ARE WRONG. Even though they WILL work without sort, they will not update properly when you go to use sorting. This is due to something the ag-grid team refers to in this issue https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-react/issues/77 as initialization time properties.

```
// Initialization problem
getRowClass = (params) => {
    if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 0) {
        return this.props.classes.rowEven;
    }
};
<AgGridReact
    getRowClass={this.getRowClass}
>

// Initialization problem
getRowStyle = (params) => {
    if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 0) {
        return this.props.classes.rowEven;
    }
};
<AgGridReact
    getRowStyle={this.getRowStyle}
>

// Initialization problem
rowClassRules = {
    rowEven: 'node.rowIndex % 2 === 0',
}
rowClassRules = {
    rowEven: (params) => params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 0,
}
<AgGridReact
    rowClassRules={this.rowClassRules}
>

// Trying to change the key so a rerender happens
// Grid also listens to this so an infinite loop is likely
sortChanged = (data) => {
    this.setState({ sort: Math.random()})
}
<AgGridReact
    key={this.state.sort}
    onSortChanged={this.sortChanged}
>
```

Basically, most stuff in grid is just read once and not again, probably for performance reasons to save rerenders.

You end up with this problem when sorting when doing any of the above:
[image: bunched up evens and odds]

THE FOLLOWIUNG IS THE RIGHT WAY TO ACHIEVE EVEN ODD COLORING:
The correct way to add even/odd functionality in ag-grid is to apply custom css styles as follows:

You will need to overwrite/use ag variables as mentioned in the docs here:https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-styling/#customizing-sass-variables

The names of the variables in our case are
.ag-grid-even class name, or the .ag-grid-odd class name. You of course only need one if you just want an alternating color to help with visibility. For our purposes we only needed one.

Here is how this process looked in our repo:
1. Make a custom css file that overwrites/uses some of these ag- class variable names. We call it ag-theme-custom.css (I believe it needs to be a css file).

[image: custom theme file example one]

[image: custom theme file example 2]

Note: We also have sass variables so this file just has a comment that this color I am adding in css is the value for our variable $GREY_100 so you don't need that part

[image: import the file]

[image: Example of passing this stuff into the parent wrapper around the component]

You now will get the same result but it will still work when sorting.
[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

You can add CSS classes to each row in the following ways:

**rowClass:** Property to set CSS class for all rows. Provide either a string (class name) or array of strings (array of class names).

**getRowClass:** Callback to set class for each row individually.

```
<ag-grid-angular
    [rowClass]="rowClass"
    [getRowClass]="getRowClass"
    /* other grid options ... */>
</ag-grid-angular>

// all rows assigned CSS class 'my-green-class'
this.rowClass = 'my-green-class';

// all even rows assigned 'my-shaded-effect'
this.getRowClass = params => {
    if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 0) {
        return 'my-shaded-effect';
    }
};
```

You can define rules which can be applied to include certain CSS classes via the grid option **rowClassRules**.

The following snippet shows rowClassRules that use functions and the value from the year column:

```
<ag-grid-angular
    [rowClassRules]="rowClassRules"
    /* other grid options ... */>
</ag-grid-angular>

this.rowClassRules = {
    // apply green to 2008
    'rag-green-outer': function(params) { return params.data.year === 2008; },

    // apply amber 2004
    'rag-amber-outer': function(params) { return params.data.year === 2004; },

    // apply red to 2000
    'rag-red-outer': function(params) { return params.data.year === 2000; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the background color of an entire row in one command. You need to do it through the `cellStyle` callback setup in the `columnDefs`. This callback will be called per each cell in the row. You need to change the color of the row by changing the color of all the cells.

See the following column definition

```
{
   headerName: "Street Address", field: "StreetAddress", cellStyle: changeRowColor
}
```

You need to do this for all your columns.

Here is your `changeRowColor` function.

```
function changeRowColor(params) {

   if(params.node.data[4] === 100){
      return {'background-color': 'yellow'};    
   } 

}
```

It changes the color of a row if the value of the third cell is 100.

Answer (score 1):

I set different color for even and odd rows you can do it in any way..

```
    $scope.gridOptions.getRowStyle = function getRowStyleScheduled(params){      
       if(parseInt(params.node.id)%2==0) {
          return {'background-color': 'rgb(87, 90, 90)'}
       }else {
          return {'background-color': 'rgb(74, 72, 72)'}
       }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to set the background color conditionally(based on the row data), it is not recommended to use **rowStyle**, as written on the [row style documentation page](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-styles/):

```
// set background color on even rows
// again, this looks bad, should be using CSS classes
gridOptions.getRowStyle = function(params) {
    if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 0) {
        return { background: 'red' };
    }
}
```

Instead, you can change the row colors using css:

```
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
@import "~ag-grid-community/src/styles/ag-theme-balham/sass/ag-theme-balham-mixin";

.ag-theme-balham {
    @include ag-theme-balham((
        // use theme parameters where possible

        odd-row-background-color: red
    ));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AdapTable then the simplest way is to use a Conditional Style and apply it to a whole row.
The advantage of this is that it can be at run-time easily by users also.
https://demo.adaptabletools.com/style/aggridconditionalstyledemo

Answer (score 0):

One can provide **getRowStyle** directly on **AgGridReact** as shown below

```
    const customRowStyle = (row: any) => {
        if (row.data.error) {
            return {
                 backgroundColor: 'red'
            }
        }
        return {};
    }


     <AgGridReact
         getRowStyle = { customRowStyle }> 
         {props.dynamicColumns} 
     </AgGridReact>
```