# Ag-grid show number of rows

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I'm testing the enterprise version, and I want to know if I can show in the status bar row some custom text? (if status bar is not possible, is there an alternative?)

I want to show `X rows / Y total rows` of the table, or if that is not possible, just `X rows`

OR
`Indicators:  Blue - Manual Deposit,  Red - Failed Deposit,  Green - Success`
(with custom style to show colors in this example)

Is this possible?
(BTW, I'm using Angular 1)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You asked 2 different questions, and I'll try to explain both.

> I want to show X rows / Y total rows of the table

You have the `Y total rows` at `gridOptions.api.getModel().getRowCount()`. The `X rows` I assume refers to 'current displayed rows' and I think there's no current way of getting it. We used to though, so I may be wrong.

> Indicators:  Blue - Manual Deposit,  Red - Failed Deposit,  Green - Success

I guess you're talking about changing a cell/row style? For cell styling, have a look at [Column Definition cellClassRules](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styling/index.php). From the webpage:

> ag-Grid allows rules to be applied to include certain classes. If you use AngularJS, then this is similar to ng-class, where you specify classes as Javascript object keys, and rules as object values.

You can use it like so:

```
//'Success', 'Manual' and 'Failed' are placeholders for the actual values
// you must compare to.
cellClassRules: {
    'green': function(params) { return params.value === 'Success'},
    'blue': function(params) { return params.value === 'Manual'},
    'red': function(params) { return params.value === 'Failed'}
},
```

For entire row styling, you can achieve it with [what I explained in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34200358/how-to-provide-a-background-color-for-an-entire-row-in-ag-grid-based-on-a-certai/35935742#35935742)

```
// Again, 'Success', 'Manual' and 'Failed' are placeholders 
// for the actual values you must compare to.
gridOptions.api.getRowStyle(params) {
    switch(params.data.myColumnToCheck){
        case 'Success':
            return {'background-color': 'green'};
        case 'Manual':
            return {'background-color': 'blue'};
        case 'Fail':
            return {'background-color': 'red'};
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display current display row in ag grid by using below method
grid.api.inMemoryRowController.rowsToDisplay.length

Thanks

Comment: That didn't work for me (using angular). This is how I was able to get the total number of rows: grid.api.getDisplayedRowCount()